# VSCode C++ Compiled exe was infected with Win32:TrojanX-gen[Trj]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, antivirus, virus

I am setting up VSCode for C++, made some simple code (test.cpp) to test if things are working.

```
  #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Hello";
}
```

When I click run code the console says "Access is denied" and my antivirus pops up and says the test.exe and tempCodeRunnerFile.exe was infected with Win32:TrojanX-gen[Trj].

What exactly is Win32:TrojanX-gen[Trj] and how do I grant access so my antivirus wont pop up?

Comment: Worthless antivirus... They are usually developer-unfriendly until your app is signed and established.  Get rid of it. Unless of course if you actually have a virus that detects new executables and infects them on run, in which case your AV is super useless.

Comment: I think this is more of a how do I add an exclusion to some unknown antivirus software? For that there are better StackExchange sites.

Comment: First, you should find out whether it's a false positive at all.

Comment: That is a good point. If you scan your computer and it is not infected then you can assume your "Hello World!" application is not infected and that your Antivirus software is the problem. Some antivirus software like aVast have both a sandbox mode which may interfere with c++ executable and also a popularity mode on unsigned executables. Since your executable is not digitally signed commercial software used by thousands of users it won't be seen as popular software.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well. Its simply because some antiviruses think that unsigned .exe files (which is the output of your CPP file after you compile) are some sort of malicious file. You do need to exclude this from your antivirus, and your best bet is to first find out which antivirus you have, and second go to the "exclusions" list and add either the folder you're working with, or the file itself. I'm assuming you have AVG lol Exclusions can be found in the settings of your antivirus. Right click on the icon and see if you can go to preferences or settings. Then look for exclusions, or even an advanced setting option, and keep looking for something along the exclusions nature.

Comment: Excluding the file path didn't work, I had to turn off File Scanning altogether. And besides it'll be a hassle to exclude every single file path anyways. I still want to know what "Win32:TrojanX-gen[Trj]" is though.

Comment: ***And besides it'll be a hassle to exclude every single file path anyway*** That is one reason you should have your code in a separate folder than your other files. For me I have a totally separate drive x: I can exclude the entire drive because I know its only my code.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an exception to the folder which contains your c++ code. (The whole folder). It did the job for mine ^-^

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).